# Network Utilization in Task manager reaches 100%

Tags: windows-10, home-networking

More of a mild curiosity, and some basic research mostly yield utilization showing 0% or other low values.

I was downloading a game and noticed Task manager claimed I was at peak utilization at only 100Mbit, despite having 500Mbit connection (and download reaching very close to it).

Nic speed, config and type: 
[image: bla]

Switch config: 
[image: bla]

Firewall config (w/speed hints): 
[image: bla]

Example of just over 100Mbit load: 
[image: bla]

Example of near 500Mbit load: 
[image: bla]

Comment: What type of connection is this? How do you connect to it?

Comment: Cable, Gbit via SMB switch(Netgear GS724T) to Firewall, then via cable modem.

Comment: Are you sure connection to the switch is actually running at 1000 Mbit/s? Please provide a screenshot of Task Manager’s network status view when the issue you describe is visible.

Comment: A 500mbit connection? How did you get that? (Ethernet typically is 10/100/1000 mbit/sec, Not 500).

Comment: I think he’s referring to the Internet uplink.

Comment: Confirm that your router, switch, and NIC all operate at 1Gbps, It sounds like you NIC is set to 100Mbps.

Comment: Added some screenshots showing the "issue"(as I said, just mildy interesting why it appears this way). @DanielB Correct, 500 Mbit connection in to the house.

Comment: Hm, you missed just [the part I wanted](http://i.stack.imgur.com/f5kyz.png). :D

Comment: I'm wondering if it isn't just reading 100% because the command queue length is constantly 1 or more.

Comment: @FrankThomas Just checked, running a speedtest monitor with Output Queue length (only queue windows have for NICs as far as I can find a metric for), Task manager had the 100% show around the 100Mbit mark as usual, but PerfMon didn't register any increase in queue length(0): http://i.imgur.com/NfvF2Iu.png Add to that: resource monitor does seem to register ~50% utilization on the nic, but no "utilization": http://i.imgur.com/cwpkbG9.png, going to remove the vnics and see if they interfer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So "luck" should have it and my OS drive hit the trash which gave me reason to dig further on this, and it seems to be related to loop-back devices created with VMware and/or VirtualBox(both makes them), both which have a low link-speed associated with them, and by extension tricks TaskManager into this "100Mbit is max" idea.

Comment: Hah! I just disabled the VMware adapters and watched Task Manager get back to sane values live. Nicely done.